# [VISUAL BASIC]how to export text file to ListView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview

Question

I have a text file that has data in this style: day,time,logtype,sessionID,loginID

For example :

2017-12-12 21:59:13,739 [7] INFO - Login.LoginUser_Authenticate - o03dx1c3hnfxz35ljee1mfcy Unknown - Login: BST028991

2017-12-12 23:59:13,839 [17] INFO - Login.LoginUser_Authenticate - o03dx1c3hnfxz35ljee1mfcy Unknown - Login: BST345991

etc.....

I want to  export text file to ListView
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwbWZ.jpg)

I created a datagridview with 5 columns (one for each data field in the text file).

I tried it with this code

```
Private Sub SetListView(ByRef myListView As ListView)
        myListView.View = View.Details
        With myListView.Columns
            .Add("day", 90)
            .Add("time", 100)
            .Add("logtype", 90)
            .Add("sessionid", 170)
            .Add("loginid", 150)
        End With

    End Sub
Private Sub OpenFolderToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenFolderToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim TextFile As IO.StreamReader
    Dim Line As String
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "LOG FILE|*.log|TEXT FILE|*.text|ALL FILE|*.*"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        For x = 0 To OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count - 1
            MessageBox.Show(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(x))

            Me.LogListView.Items.Clear()
            TextFile = New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(x), System.Text.Encoding.Default)
            Line = TextFile.ReadLine()
            Do While Line <> Nothing
                Me.LogListView.Items.Add(Line)
                Line = TextFile.ReadLine()
            Loop

            TextFile.Close()
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

his code is wrong, when it's loaded, text  is only one column
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwbWZ.jpg)

Comment: Looking at your example I can't quite see how you would break it up with a delimiter. Usually you do this with a `,`. Your headers suggest this but your examples do not. If you can clarify that then you can split on `,` and use this to push to a `ListItem` and `SubItems` which is what you need. To be honest I think you may struggle to do this with how the file is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

you need to explode the line and create new ListViewItem for multicolumn listviewitem add.
please refer to the following code:

```
String[] arr = new String[5];
arr = explode(line);

var item = new ListViewItem(new[] {arr[0],arr[1],arr[2],arr[3],arr[4]});
myListView.Items.Add(item);
```

This is "Lightning3" code, i help to do formatting.

```
Dim arr As [String]() = New [String](4) {} 
arr = explode(line) 

Dim item = New ListViewItem(New () {arr(0), arr(1), arr(2), arr(3), arr(4)})
myListView.Items.Add(item)
```